# How to select value contain character ' in statement

Tags: sql, oracle

How to select statement when the value contain special character " ' " in between of the value.

> Select * from tablename where columnone= 'He's'

The statement give me error, because have character(') in the value:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Double it, i.e. `'He''s'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional way is to "Doubling-Up" of Single Quotes,

```
select * 
  from tablename 
 where columnone= 'He''s';
```

Alternatively you can use `q` operator for quoting string literals containing quotes. Using this you can put the actual string within `q'[actual string]'`

```
select * 
  from tablename 
 where columnone= q'[He's]';
```

Other variations with examples of using `q` operator can be found [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html#:%7E:text=Description%20Oracle%20Database%20offers%20the,starting%20delimiter%20for%20the%20literal.)